# Problem with spring mvc herbinate in many to many relationship with extra columns

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have three tables, [tables in sql servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNjIx.png) , which Solved had been created by many-many relationship. 
Solved table has a composite key, so i wrote a SolvedKey for its composite key [SolvedKey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGRb2.png)

```
@Embeddable
public class SolvedKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="userMailer")
    private String usermail;

    @Column(name="challengeID")
    private int challengeid;
```

My Entity:

Solved: [solved entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4it8w.png)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Solved")
public class Solved {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SolvedKey solvedKey;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("usermail")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("challengeid")
    private Challenge chall;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy/mm/dd")
    @Column(name = "dateSolved")
    private Date dateSolved;
```

User: [user entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49OpI.png)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Users")
public class User implements Serializable{
    // declare field
    @Id
    @Column(name="Mail")
    private String mail;
    @Column(name="Username")
    private String userName;    
    @Column(name="Password")
    private String passWord;
    @Column(name ="Validation")
    private boolean valid;
    @Column(name="Isadmin")
    @Nullable
    private boolean isAdmin;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Solved> challs = new ArrayList<Solved>();
```

Challenge: [Challenge entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwkaC.png)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Challenges")
public class Challenge implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="challengName")
    private String challengeName;

    @Column(name = "score")
    private int score;

    @Column(name="fileAttach")
    private String fileAttach;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="hint")
    private String hint;

    @Column(name="major")
    private String major;

    @Column(name = "flag")
    private String flag;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "chall",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Solved> users = new ArrayList<Solved>();
```

But i don't sure that it's correct. And when i try to request list of challenges of a user:

```
public void getListSolved(String mail){
        User user = getUserByMail(mail);
        System.out.println("User: " + user.getUserName());
        System.out.println("Challs: " + user.getChalls());
        user.getChalls().forEach(
                (chall) -> System.out.println("Chall: "+ chall.getChall().getChallengeName()+ " | Date: " + chall.getDateSolved())
        );
    }
```

It failed because of the invalid column "user_Mail" , but i can't find where is that column in my code.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
    org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:449)
    org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:202)
    org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:137)
    org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
    org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:100)
    org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:693)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:92)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1893)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:555)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:260)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:551)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:140)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:526)
    java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    wargame.dao.UserDAO.getListSolved(UserDAO.java:154)
    wargame.mainController.UserController.userInfo(UserController.java:285)
    wargame.mainController.UserController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$b3d9caac.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:710)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:643)
    wargame.mainController.UserController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9bfbb734.userInfo(<generated>)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
root cause

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'user_Mail'.
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:196)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1458)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:388)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:338)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4016)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1414)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:176)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:151)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:281)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
    org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:449)
    org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:202)
    org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:137)
    org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
    org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:100)
    org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:693)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:92)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1893)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:555)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:260)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:551)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:140)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:526)
    java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    wargame.dao.UserDAO.getListSolved(UserDAO.java:154)
    wargame.mainController.UserController.userInfo(UserController.java:285)
    wargame.mainController.UserController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$b3d9caac.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:710)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:643)
    wargame.mainController.UserController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9bfbb734.userInfo(<generated>)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want reference column of User in Solved entity to be usermail, I suggest to design your entity as following. Main difference is that instead of having User and Challenge in Solved use it in SolvedKey as reference entity and don't forget to override equal and hashCode in SolvedKey.

SolvedKey Entity

```
@Embeddable
public class SolvedKey implements Serializable {

       @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       @JoinColumn(name = "usermail" , referencedColumnName = "Mail")
       private User user;

       @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       private Challenge chall;
```

Soved Entity

```
@Entity
public class Solved {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SolvedKey solvedKey;
```

User -> to Solved relationship

```
@Entity
public class User {

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "solvedKey.user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private List<Solved> challs = new ArrayList<Solved>();
```

Challenge -> to Solved relationship

```
@Entity
public class Challenge {


     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "solvedKey.chall",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private List<Solved> users = new ArrayList<Solved>();
```

When I execute spring boot app , hibernate ddl is as following.

```
create table Solved (
   dateSolved date,
    chall_ID integer not null,
    usermail varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (chall_ID, usermail)
)


alter table Solved 
   add constraint FKx2kp7aliijq7g7xq0j4huqb4 
   foreign key (chall_ID) 
   references Challenge

alter table Solved 
   add constraint FKhycu95r961terhbackiixqwns 
   foreign key (usermail) 
   references User
```

Comment: Omg, work like a charm, thanks so much, you save my life, i lost almost a week just because of this :((